# Put a circle around elements in a matrix environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, nodes

So I'm trying to put circles around 6,8,10,18 in row 1-4 respectively, however this does give me an error warning saying "missing $ inserted"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{tikz}



\begin{document}

$   
\text{M}=\begin{pmatrix}
4 & \tikz\node[draw,circle]{6} & 4 & 5 \\ 
3 & 8 & 1 & 6 \\ 
2 & 9 & 2 & 10 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 18
\end{pmatrix}
$ 

\end{document}
```

How can I correct this error, because positioning various $ around the command hasn't helped so far.

Comment: This code is not compileable, you must give the entire code starting with `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}` which allows you to reproduce your error.

Comment: it's a fragment of the code, it's embedded in a article environment

Comment: The fragment should now be compileable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tikz code must always be ended with a semicolon.

```
4 & \tikz\node[draw,circle]{6}; & 4 & 5 \\
```

[image: matrice]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

$   
\text{M}=
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & \tikz\node[draw,circle]{6}; & 4 & 5 \\ 
3 & 8 & 1 & 6 \\ 
2 & 9 & 2 & 10 \\ 
1 & 2 & 3 & 18
\end{pmatrix}
$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ChristianSinger It is not necessary to use `mathtools`, `tikz` has a native matrix management that simplifies syntax.

Answer (score 14):

With a `tikz matrix` you can get a better alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\[
\text{M}=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\matrix[
    matrix of math nodes, 
    minimum size=16pt,
    row sep=2pt,
    column sep=2pt,
    left delimiter=(,
    right delimiter=), 
    inner xsep=0pt
    ]{
    4 & |[draw, circle]|6 & 4 & 5 \\ 
    3 & |[draw, circle]|8 & 1 & 6 \\ 
    2 & 9 & 2 & |[draw, circle]|10 \\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & |[draw, circle]|18\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks alot nicer than my result with a regular matrix, thanks!

Comment: Would there be a way to change the size of circle?

Comment: @Le4M Yes, of course, you can. Just write `draw, circle, minimum size=<your_desired_size>`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution with an ordinary matrix and `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

$ \psset{framesep=1pt, linewidth=0.4pt}
\text{M}=\begin{pmatrix}
4 & \pscirclebox{6} & 4 & 5 \\
3 & \pscirclebox{8} & 1 & 6 \\
2 & 9 & 2 & \pscirclebox{10} \\
1 & 2 & 3 & \pscirclebox{18}
\end{pmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since longer numbers rather need to be highlighted by ellipses than by circles, and multicolored circles can be useful, here is another example of how to use F. Pantigny's answer to get different colored ellipses:

```
 \begin{equation}
A = 
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1mm}
\begin{bNiceMatrix}
0.0    &0.86   &-1.91  &-0.51  & 1.14\\
-1.47  & 0.0   &-0.57  &-0.33  & 0.038\\
 2.20  &-1.93  & 0.0   &-0.36  &-2.04\\
-2.42  &-2.97  & 1.78  & 0.0   &-0.59\\
-2.55  &-0.61  &-0.58  & 0.85  & 0.0
\CodeAfter
%% uses self-defined colours (see default packages/newcommands.tex)
  \tikz \draw[color = red]    (1-3) ellipse (7mm and 3mm)
                                    (3-1) ellipse (7mm and 3mm);
  \tikz \draw[color = green] (1-5) ellipse (7mm and 3mm)
                                    (5-1) ellipse (7mm and 3mm);
  \tikz \draw[color = blue]     (3-4) ellipse (7mm and 3mm)
                                    (4-3) ellipse (7mm and 3mm);
  \tikz \draw[color = black](4-5) ellipse (7mm and 3mm)
                                    (5-4) ellipse (7mm and 3mm);
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\label{matrix: competition matrix oscillating}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `nicematrix` and `Tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$M = 
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1mm}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
4 & 6 & 4 & 5 \\
3 & 8 & 1 & 6 \\
2 & 9 & 2 & 10 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 18 
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (1-2) circle (1.7mm) 
              (2-2) circle (1.7mm) 
              (3-4) circle (2.1mm) 
              (4-4) circle (2.1mm) ;
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]