# How can I put some of the entries of a matrix inside of a red circle like in the image below?

Tags: matrices, circles

I have a bmatrix like this:

[image: original]

and I want to change it to something similar to the picture below. How can I do it?

[image: second]

**Edit 1:** Code of my matrix is below:

```
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community. Excuse me for this comment: but you have tried something or have you taken your images in the net? Surely this question it is a duplicate.

Comment: Welcome to Text.SE. can you provide the code of the matrix?

Comment: @Roland Hi, look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457209/put-a-circle-around-elements-in-a-matrix-environment

Comment: thank you @Sebastiano how can I flag your comment as the solution?

Comment: @ErselHengirmen Don't worry...this is a wonderful community. :-)

Comment: Also see [Highlight elements in the matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40028/5764).

Comment: It does yes @werner thank you btw  `Highlight elements in the matrix` helps a lot too  thank you so much.

Comment: If you want to change the color of the circle you can see here (for example): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481168/customize-circled-numbers. There are a lot of answers.

Comment: @Sebastiano. Wow I didn't know that was even possible. You are right this community is wonderful :)